# Simple count of unique items in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

looking for a count of unique filenames are contained in a simple javascript array.

I have a javascript array that combines two arrays via

```
var total_dl = prev_dl.concat(new_dl).sort();
```

One is a json_encode() from a php variable, the other is made from the checkbox values selected on a form. This outputs a simple list of file names, ie

```
    cat.jpg, dog.jpg, elephant.jpg, cat.jpg, lion.jpg, dog.jpg
```

I can then refine this into an array of distinct values, with

```
var unique_dl = total_dl.filter((value,pos) => {return total_dl.indexOf(value) == pos;} );
```

to output

```
    cat.jpg, dog.jpg, elephant.jpg, lion.jpg
```

I now just need to output a count of how many unique/distinct filenames are contained here, ie 4. First thought was to use length

```
var count_unique = unique_dl.length;
```

which seems to give a value of prev_dl + 1, unchanged for whatever new_dl is made up of. Another try with

```
var count_unique = unique_dl.filter(function(val, i, arr) { 
    return arr.indexOf(val) === i;
}).length;
```

fails too (have I misformatted here?).

Any pointers/steers here would be very welcome, thanks.

Comment: Could you provide an example of data (`prev_dl` and `new_dl`) where `unique_dl.length` is `prev_dl.length + 1` **_AND_** this is a wrong answer? For the data in the question it seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: When I run this against `var total_dl = ['cat.jpg', 'dog.jpg', 'elephant.jpg', 'cat.jpg', 'lion.jpg', 'dog.jpg']`, `unique_dl.length` returns 4

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object. It takes an iterable and returns a set with unique items.

```
const arr = 'cat.jpg, dog.jpg, elephant.jpg, cat.jpg, lion.jpg, dog.jpg'.split(', ');
const unique = new Set(arr);

console.log(unique.size);
```

And if you want to convert it back to an array, you can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
const uniqueArr = Array.from(unique);

console.log(uniqueArr);
```

```js
const arr = 'cat.jpg, dog.jpg, elephant.jpg, cat.jpg, lion.jpg, dog.jpg'.split(', ');
const unique = new Set(arr);

console.log('Set size', unique.size);

const uniqueArr = Array.from(unique);

console.log('Unique array', uniqueArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The unique_dl.length solution works for me.
Building unique_dl thou needs O(n^2) time, so it's slower than:

```
function count_unique(in_array) {
    if(in_array.length == 0)
        return 0;
    var sorted = input_array.sort();
    var unique_count = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < sorted.length; ++i)
        if(sorted[i - 1] != sorted[i])
            ++unique_count;
    return unique_count;
 }
```

Since it uses just O(n log(n)) time

Comment: You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925864/counting-unique-element-in-large-array

Answer (score 0):

I have test your example and as @phil said, with the data you provide the result is 4.

```
var total_dl = [
  'cat.jpg', 'dog.jpg', 'elephant.jpg', 'cat.jpg',
  'lion.jpg', 'dog.jpg'
]
var unique_dl = total_dl.filter((value,pos) => {return total_dl.indexOf(value) == pos;} );  

console.log(unique_dl)
var count_unique = unique_dl.length; 
console.log(count_unique)
```

https://jsbin.com/rolaxuh/1/edit?html,js,console